# How to initialize at js new map in gmaps4rails 1.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am trying by this example: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383129/rendering-a-gmap-through-an-ajax-call-with-gmaps4rails) initialize the seckond map by clicking ajax button but map is not initialized. I working on latest version gmaps4rails. My source:

```
= gmaps("map_options" => { "detect_location" => true, "center_on_user" => true, "auto_adjust" => true, "zoom" => 12, "auto_zoom" => false })

%button#ajax_map Ajax Map

#map_container
  #map2
```

js:

```
$(function() {
  $('#ajax_map').click(function(){
    $('#map_container').addClass('map_container');
    $('#map2').addClass('gmaps4rails_map');
    Gmaps.map2.map_options.detect_location = true;
    Gmaps.map2.map_options.center_on_user = true;
    Gmaps.map2.initialize();
  });
});
```

css:

```
.map_container {
  width: 600px;
}

#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
#map2 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 1.0.0, I create 'real' js objects.

So you need to instantiate it:

```
Gmaps.map2 = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle(); // for a google map
```